# Cant get json from response ajaxLink in Yii

Tags: php, ajax, json, yii

I have a ajaxLink what send request to controller, where I return encoded json string:

```
return CJSON::encode(array(
            'up' => ...,
            'down' => ...,
        ));
```

In view, ajaxLink attributes:

```
'dataType' => 'json',
'success'  => 'js: function(data) {
     console.log(data); // equal to null
 }'
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo CJSON::encode(array(
            'up' => ...,
            'down' => ...,
        ));
```

Comment: this help. but in my opinion it is looks a little bit creepy. thanks :)